# How to read back opengl processed data from GPU to host memory

Tags: opengl-es, yuv, rgba

I want to convert my yuv420 image into rgb888 image. i got below link for this.
http://www.fourcc.org/source/YUV420P-OpenGL-GLSLang.c

This program works fine for me. 
Now i want to read back my processed rgb data from GPU into host memory. i have tried to do glGetTexImage but it gives me only last binded texture data.

Can any one tell how can i read back my processed RGB data from GPU into host memory?

I also have another question that if i will get success to read back my data from GPU into host memory then it will be RGB or RGBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `glReadPixels` command. The syntax is `glReadPixels(GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, GLvoid * data)

`x` and `y` specify the location of the lower left corner of the rectangle you to read from thr framebuffer, `format` accepts `GL_ALPHA`, `GL_RGB`, and `GL_RGBA`, `type` is the type of the pixel data, `data` is a pointer to the returned data array.
`format` specifies if the data will be RGB, RGBA or alpha.

You can get more information at the [Khronos specification page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have tried below code to get processed RGB values and write it to file but when i tried to open RGB image it shows wrong one. Can you tell me how can i use glreadpixels() for 720x576 yuv image.                                                                                                      
        int write;
        fp=fopen("result_t.rgb","w+");
        unsigned char pixels[1244160] = {0};
        glReadPixels(0,0,720,576,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pixels);
        write = fwrite (pixels,1,720*576 *3,fp); 
        printf ("write = %d\n",write); fclose (fp);

Comment: Sorry for the above post. Thanks for your reply.  I have tried below code to get processed RGB values and write it to file but when i tried to open RGB image using vooya it gives me 180' rotated image that is my 1st line of original pixels became last line of pixels and 2nd line of original pixels became 2nd last line of pixels and so on. can you tell me why it happens?
glReadPixels(0,0,720,576,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pixels);

Comment: @PragneshPatel No problem. It is flipped because OpenGL has Y axis pointing upward, while the other software/screens have it pointing down. You need to flip it yourself either as an array or when you write it to a file.